# Is any better way of using @font-face

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

with this code i can get the cross browser compatibility, but the problem is, here i need to add lots of file type of the same font, how to avoid that and still able to get the cross browser compatibility?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Name';
    src: url('location.eot');
    src: url('location.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('location.woff') format('woff'),
         url('location.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('location.svg#Name') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: As it stands your question doesn't really make sense.  Can you explain in more detail exactly what your problem is?

Comment: @TobyAllen here you can see, i have to add .ttf .woff .svg .eot files to the server,
i need to achieve the cross browser compatibility with less files and less overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google font is a easiest and I think best way to use different fonts on a webpage.
So I'll recommend Google Font unless you need something more extra like iconic font or any other unique fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You cant really avoid it as the browsers has different support. If the issue is that you don't want to host them yourself [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts) has a wide range of good fonts that you can use for free. But if you have a font that is more unique then as stated you can't do it in any other way.

Comment: Then unfortunately `@font-face`is the only way. Except if you skip support for a browser/s. What's your biggest problem with adding the fonts to the server?

Comment: actually i had only one format with me and it is .ttf, and don't know whether i have the license to convert it and upload the converted files to the server.

Comment: I usually buy and license webkit for a font, or use Google fonts at times. There is online sites and tools that can convert your .ttf to the required font types for `@font-face`. You would have to check with your client what the license say about converting/online use. It's up to you and your client to do what is right (obviously buying the rights).